# Enviar un parámetro de un botón a otro

Tags: vb.net

Buen día,

Me gustaría que alguien me explicara como hago para enviar un parámetro con un valor desde un botón  a otro, tengo el siguiente código:

Desde este evento llamo al otro botón y le envió el parámetro:

```
Protected Sub btnBuscarToro_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnBuscarToro.Click

    ASPxButton1_Click(Nothing, Nothing, 1)
    PopBuscaAnimal.ShowOnPageLoad = True

End Sub
```

El siguiente evento lo recibe:

```
 Protected Sub ASPxButton1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs, ByVal i As Int32)

    Dim valor As Int32 = i

    Dim Registro As String = gvAnimales.GetRowValues(gvAnimales.FocusedRowIndex, "RegistroAnimal").ToString()

    If Registro <> "" Then

        txtReA.Text = gvAnimales.GetRowValues(gvAnimales.FocusedRowIndex, "RegistroAnimal").ToString()

    End If

    PopBuscaAnimal.ShowOnPageLoad = False

End Sub
```

Cuando ejecuto el programa me sale el siguiente error:

> El método 'Protected Sub ASPxButton1_Click(sender As Object, e As
>   System.EventArgs, i As Integer)' no tiene una signatura compatible con
>   el delegado 'Delegate Sub EventHandler(sender As Object, e As
>   System.EventArgs)'.

Alguien me puede ayudar.

Comment: Creo que te equivocaste al copiar le código, los dos bloques son idénticos

Comment: Si, que pena, ya lo corregí.

Comment: que quieres hacer? porque quizas tienes tu logica mal

Comment: Buenas compañero, ¿No será más sencillo crear un método que sea llamado desde ambos botones? Un saludo!

Comment: el método acepta tres parámetros , sin embargo por definición sobra el último, tienes que eliminarlo (i) y pasar el valor de otra manera, ej: accediendo al botón sender as object por ejemplo y guardando el valor ahi

Answer (score 0):

Puedes utilizar la propiedad TAG. Sirve para añadir cualquier cosa a los controles (valores,objetos,...).

En el evento click del btnBuscarToro (boton emisor), estableces en el Tag del otro boton, el valor que quieras.

Despues, en el evento click del ASPxButton1 (boton receptor), el sender sería el mismo boton, con lo que tendrías el valor del TAG establecido en el evento click del boton emisor.

Intenta con esto.

```
    Protected Sub btnBuscarToro_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnBuscarToro.Click

        ASPxButton1.Tag=1
        PopBuscaAnimal.ShowOnPageLoad = True

    End Sub

    Protected Sub ASPxButton1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs)

        Dim btn As Button= (Button) sender
        Dim i as Int32 = CInt(btn.Tag.ToString())

        Dim Registro As String = gvAnimales.GetRowValues(gvAnimales.FocusedRowIndex, "RegistroAnimal").ToString()

        If Registro <> "" Then

            txtReA.Text = gvAnimales.GetRowValues(gvAnimales.FocusedRowIndex, "RegistroAnimal").ToString()

        End If

        PopBuscaAnimal.ShowOnPageLoad = False

    End Sub
```